# Creating table with plugin is not working

Tags: plugin-development, database, table

After reading many question and answers and many had asked the same question I have been following the same instruction as the people instructed but my bad it's not working I have used

- dbDelta($sql)
- $wpdb->query($sql)

It's not working

sample code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: ContactUs
Plugin URI: 
Description: Simple Plugin Developed for Testing purpose
Version: 1.0.0
Author: rajeshw
Author URI: codelisense.com
*/  

//Creating table
    function contact_installation(){
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix. "contactus";

        if($wpdb->get_var ('SHOW TABLES LIKE' .$table_name ) != $table_name){
            $sql= "CREATE TABLE" .$table_name. "(
                   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                   firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                   lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                   email VARCHAR(50),
                   reg_date TIMESTAMP
                   )";
            require_once (ABSPATH. 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
            $wpdb->query($sql);

            //had replaced the above line with this line
            dbDelta($sql);
        }
    }
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'contact_installation');
```

Table is not been created... Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dot and quote notation is funky. Try this:

```
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'" ) != $table_name){
    $sql= "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
           id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
           firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
           lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
           email VARCHAR(50),
           reg_date TIMESTAMP
           );";
    require_once (ABSPATH. 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

Create a file like "my_db.php" and paste this code:

```
global $table_version;
$table_version = "1.0";

function func_table_contactus(){
    creat_table_contactus();
}

function creat_table_contactus(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $table_version;

    $table_contactus = $wpdb->prefix."contactus";
    $slider_ver = get_option("table_version");

    $check_table_contactus = $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_contactus'");

    if($check_table_contactus != $table_contactus ||  $slider_ver != $table_version ) {
         $sql= "CREATE TABLE" .$table_name. "(
                   id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                   firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                   lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                   email VARCHAR(50),
                   reg_date TIMESTAMP
           PRIMARY KEY (id)
               )";

    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);

    update_option("table_version", $table_version);
    }
    else{
        add_option("table_version", $table_version);
    }

}
```

and in your plugin main file

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: ContactUs
Plugin URI: 
Description: Simple Plugin Developed for Testing purpose
Version: 1.0.0
Author: rajeshw
Author URI: codelisense.com
*/  

require "my_db.php";
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'func_table_contactus');
```

Hope you find your solution

Comment: OOh..!! this too works.. Thank you so much for you reply...